# Can we set a php/mysql environment with grunt?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, gruntjs

I'm working on a team project which i'm responsible of workflow.
I initially used Vagrant as environment, but simultaneous database updates were complicated.

So i chose Yeoman to set up the project.
But to keep the control of the team environment, i want to set up myself the msql database and the php's version.
It is possible with grunt ? To run a local server with php and mysql ?

Cheers,

Antoine

Comment: I would imagine managing server software is outside the realms of a client-side task manager.

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/generator-slim Apparently it's possible, but i don't know how :)

Comment: Looking at that package, it seems to pull down Slim—a framework written in PHP—but not actually the versions of PHP and MySQL binaries to create a development environment. I imagine any workarounds using Grunt will be more effort than just using Vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

For the php server part I recommend this grunt plugin

https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php